# How to pass native ReferenceError object stack to console in a JavaScript try catch?

Tags: javascript, error-handling, try-catch, stack-trace, error-logging

In JavaScript, when using a try catch, how can I get the native Chrome ReferenceError object to the console as it would normally be logged? I can get close by using the Error object's stack property, but it logs the errors differently:

```
try {
    bet you can't run this you dumb computer;
}
catch(error) {
    console.log(error.stack);
}
```

When running the above, I get the following in the console:

[image]

While this is slightly helpful, clicking on the line number takes me to the console.log(error.stack) line in the code, not the error.

Without the try catch, the error looks like this:

[image]

and clicking on the line number will take me exactly to where the original error occurred. So how can I get this native Chrome error object to pass to the catch and then log to the console so that I can navigate to the original error and line that was thrown as it would normally be without the try catch in place?

Comment: What you have is a `SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier` which happens even before the try is evaluated. Please show us your actual code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it'll work with the [`error` method from the console object](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/console-reference#error):

```
try {
    bet you can not run this you dumb computer;
}
catch(error) {
    console.error(error);
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This worked. I actually tried this earlier, but was clicking on the wrong section of the stack trace. So if you do this, you have to click on the line numbers in the stack trace below the first line, not on the far right side of the console, which will take you to the console.log().